# How to wrap text within reactive splom lattice plot?

Tags: r, shiny, scatter-plot, lattice

Within my shiny app, I am having my users select n number of attributes to plot within my `splom()` call, which essentially follows these steps:

1. User chooses a number.
2. User chooses variables.
3. Code subsets my data set based on users choices.
4. Splom is called in a very simple call, similar to: `lplot <- splom(data_subset)`.

However, since the panels within `splom()` are being labeled based on the attribute name (which is reactive, so I can't label ahead of time) and the names are very long you can't read them.

Does anyone know if there is a way to wrap text within the splom panel outputs? The wrapping would be done on the attribute reactive value, so it wouldn't be done on a string.

This is what my output looks like:

[image: splom]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After subsetting in **step 3**, you can manipulate the names of the data subset to wrap appropriately.

```
## Subset the data in whatever way shiny does (here's a reproducible example)
irisSub <- subset(iris, select = grepl("Width", names(iris)))
```

Then

1. **Replace** "word" separators with spaces. In your example, you probably just need `"_"`

   ```
   names(irisSub) <- gsub("\\.|_", " ", names(irisSub))
   ```
2. **Wrap** these strings at a fairly narrow width. You might have to experiment with other widths here.

   ```
   wrapList <- strwrap(names(irisSub), width = 10, simplify = FALSE)
   ```
3. **Paste** these strings back together with a linebreak (`\n`) in between and assign them to names of data subset

   ```
   names(irisSub) <- vapply(wrapList, paste, collapse = "\n", FUN.VALUE = character(1))
   ```
4. `splom` should **respect** the line breaks

   ```
   splom(irisSub)
   ```

   [image]